# CuCl via electrolysis of HCl

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-chemistry, electrolysis, halides

I need a solution of CuCl in HCl.  Since CuCl reagent is such a pain to source and work with (because it oxidizes so quickly) I was thinking that I could create the solution simply via electrolysis of copper electrodes in HCl.

Is anyone aware of research on this electrolytic reaction?  I don't have time right now to look for side reactions or to play with parameters (solution strength, voltage, etc.).

(Unfortunately I can't find any research specific to this, because CuCl-HCl electrolysis is a popular method of generating hydrogen, so all searches return papers on *that*.)